# Android Deprecated Annotation is deprecated, what's the replacement?

Tags: java, android, annotations, deprecated

[image: Deprecaated]
According to [Official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Deprecated) Deprecated itself is deprecated in API level S. So what's the replacement for Deprecated which itself is deprecated?

Edit: Added web archive [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210218192448/https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Deprecated) for historical reference.

Comment: quite ironic, i wonder if they used the annotation on itself

Comment: @assylias Based on the [list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels) "level S" will be API 31 aka Android 12 which will be released this year (API 30 is "R" and "S" is next in alphabet).

Comment: @Robert How can something being deprecated in an API level which is still not released?

Comment: According to the [time table of Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/overview) the first developer preview versions should be available. Most likely those versions are not yet public and only available for Android device manufacturer. Therefore "not released" may be wrong, it is just not released publicly.

Comment: @Robert can't argue with that but still what's the replacement?

Comment: May be Google wants us to switch to `kotlin.Deprecated` (which requires to have a message)?

Comment: looks like it was a mistake , https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180705308

Comment: Live by the sword, die by the sword

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It was a documentation bug.  (And it has been fixed!)

The `Deprecated` annotation is not really deprecated.

Apparently what happened is that the source code for `Deprecated` contained this in its javadoc comments:

```
 * @apiNote
 * It is strongly recommended that the reason for deprecating a program element
 * be explained in the documentation, using the {@code @deprecated}
 * javadoc tag.
```

Apparently, the `{@code @deprecated}` was interpreted as an `@deprecated` javadoc tag by the [`metalava`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/metalava/) tool.  This caused `metalava` to inject the "missing" `@Deprecated` annotations into the ".class" files in the Android JAR file.  Presumably, the injected annotation was then incorporated into the generated javadocs on the website.

Kudos to [Manohar Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6478047/manohar-reddy) for finding the [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180705308) in the issue tracker.

You can find the fix that they made [here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/libcore/+/1601554/1/ojluni/src/main/java/java/lang/Deprecated.java#b59).

---

For what it is worth, `java.lang.Deprecated` is a class that originates in the Oracle / OpenJDK Java (i.e. standard Java) class libraries.  Android *wouldn't / shouldn't* deliberately deprecate it without a very good reason.  It would create another hurdle to Java <-> Android portability.

Comment: kudos to this reddit comment https://www.reddit.com/r/mAndroidDev/comments/lr1w8s/deprecated_is_now_deprecated/gok7tv1

Comment: that would have been hilarious, though :)